QWC2 quick start - port error
Working through the QWC2 quick start instructions: Running QWC2 as part of qwc-services, I have the QGIS server failing to start, giving the following error:

(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs

Googling indicates this is due to the apache server expecting to run on port 80, but the container isn't running with root priviledges. Correct me if I'm wrong (please) - but it seems I need to change the QGIS server port to something above 1024.
How do I do this within the qwc-service stack and ensure that everything else knows where it is?
